# Duplicate a Filtered Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters

We a Filtered Data Extension, the original thought was to create additional Data Extensions from this Filtered Data Extension (basically functioning like a template) so the filter criteria didn't have to be added each time.

Is the only way to do this is to use Data Filters and Filter Activities? So we'd need to create 2 objects instead of 1?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Create a copy of the original DE (the one you filtered)
2. Create a query activity and use the SQL code as below
3. Create a filter activity to run the data filter
4. Create an automation to refresh the data filter first, then run the query (use multiple queries and DE's as you need, one each step)
5. When you run the automation it will run the filter and then place everything from the filtered DE into the DE's targeted by the SQL query

   select * from 
   [filtered DE] with (nolock)

Destination: Copy of the original DE

Alternatively, create multiple data filter activities using the same data filter but make the activity place results in different DE's.
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/filter_activity/